# Passing setState hooks as props in React, using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an error: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1` from typescript for the following code:

**child component:**

```js
onChange={(e) => {
                            setBrandSelectionObjectState((prev) => {
                                const newObj = {};
                                Object.keys(prev).forEach((keyTypeId) => {
                                    newObj[keyTypeId] = e.target.checked;
                                });
                                return newObj;
                            });
                        }}
```

The error is concerning the `setBrandSelectionObjectState()` function. I'm guessing the `1` argument that the error is referring to is the `(prev)`.

I'm receiving the above `setBrandSelectionObjectState()` into my child component as follows:

**child component:**

```js
interface SelectGarmentTypesParams {
    setTeeTypeSelectionObjectState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SelectionObjectBooleans>>;
}

export function SelectGarmentTypes({
    setTeeTypeSelectionObjectState,
}: SelectGarmentTypesParams): JSX.Element {
...
```

I am passing the `setBrandSelectionObjectState()` function from a parent component:

**parent component:**

```js
export interface NewTeeTypesObject {
    newteetypes_id: number;
    manufacturer: string;
    description: string;
    availablecolors: string[];
    imageurls: string[];
    availablecountries: string[];
    notavailablecountries: string[];
    garmenttype: string;
    yearsavailable: number[];
    materials: { [key: string]: number }[] | null;
    weight: number;
}

const [brandSelectionObjectState, setBrandSelectionObjectState] = useState<SelectionObjectBooleans>(...)
```

But I'm unsure where in my code I've gone wrong or what to change?

Comment: While you're using `setBrandSelectionObjectState` inside your child component I cannot see it's definition in child props' type signature. Can you provide it?

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/wOaq6m naive implementation of your example shows no errors

Comment: I'm sorry aleksxor, I'm not sure what you mean. When I hover over the  ```setBrandSelectionObjectState``` in my child params it gives me the tooltip with this info: ```var setTeeTypeSelectionObjectState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<SelectionObjectBooleans>>``` - but I don't think that's what you mean is it?

Interesting that your tsplay sandbox shows no errors. I'm too new to typescript to be able to glean what the difference is. I'll try putting together a codesandbox to see if I can recreate.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error TS shows you in console? Error text, error position, etc...

Comment: I've actually just figured out the problem and it was just down to a silly oversight where I was using the wrong Interface. I wouldn't have figured it out if you hadn't shown that it should be working in the tsplay sandbox though. Thanks so much for your help!